# How to incorporate RSA Adaptive Authentication in Java?

Tags: java, xml, security, authentication, rsa

I'm reading some pdf from RSA (now EMC) and all I see for using the API is through xml.  How can I use Java to use this security? I am looking to use it for authentication.  The username and password will be stored on my end, and security questions and the like will be stored on RSA's end. I know that I have to send messages (i.e. analyze request messages and authenticate requests) Do I use xml AND java? Or just java, and how?

edit: I'm using the Adaptive Authentication API

edit: Sorry I should've specified, I had forgotten that RSA was an algorithm as well.  I am talking about RSA as in the company.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say "stored on RSA's end" do you mean you will talking to some service hosted by RSA? I.e. are you talking about using RSA (the company) rather than  RSA (the algorithm)?

Comment: I'm talking about RSA(the company). I forgot that Java had RSA algorithms, but thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

RSA's Adaptive Authentication product uses [SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/) for clients to integrate with. You will want to select one of the many Java SOAP toolkits and develop your code using the methodology of that toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Java incorporates JCE (Java Cryptographic Extensions) which includes RSA algorithms for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JAAS, JCE and JSSE api for java.

see [Java SE security](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html)

If you intend to use webservices , you have to use ws-security throw SSL with callback methods  for the password.